# Defining a variable range based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a formula that automatically inserts a given value into a cell. The issue is that the value constantly changes so I can't have just one flat reference cell.

Example:
In the given chart, I want to find a way for the amount for "P" trans. to automatically equal the amount for the most recent "S" trans. I can't just treat this as a chart within a chart because the data will be ongoing.

[Variable Range Based on Cell Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSTZY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there can be only 2 distinct values, i.e. P or S, for this specific problem I would simply put a formula in `D2`

`=if(B2="P",C1,C2)`

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear with what I was looking for. I'm wanting the formula to be in column C and then for every "P" trans. a formula will automatically generate the amount for the most recent "S" trans.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier in column `D` how will you put the formula for all the rows? And you can simply modify the formula above if you want to do that.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and that would be an answer. However, this is just a fraction of a much larger worksheet that is simplified in order to make it easily understandable. After researching it more, I believe this is an area where VBA will be useful in order to maintain the integrity and cleanliness of the worksheet.